# Program not behaving correctly

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am trying to create a program for a user entering information on books (Name, Author, Publishing year and price). And then I want to be able to get a list of the books' names published after 2000 and their average price.
At first, I thought of using arrays in an array, but after going through similar questions I chose to make a `Book` class:

```
public class Books {
 public static String name;
 public static String author;
 public static int year;
 public static float price;
 public static float sum = 0.0F;
 public static float avrg = 0.0F;
```

I don't know if the following are necessary, but I did it as I've seen it in a lot of examples:

```
public String getName () {
            return name;
        }
        public String getAuthor () {
            return author;
        }
        public int getYear () {
            return year;
        }
        public float getPrice () {
            return price;
        }
```

Then, I am trying to take the user input and store my new objects in an array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter details for five books!");     
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    Books [] book = new Books[5];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (i=0; i < book.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Book Title, Author Last Name, Year and Price:");
        String name = in.next();
        String author = in.next();
        int year = in.nextInt();
        float price = in.nextFloat();
        }
```

And here I want to find the exact books and calculate their average price:

```
for (j=0; j<book.length; j++){
        if (Books.year >= 2000) {
            System.out.println("Books published after 2000:"+ Books.name);
            sum = sum + Books.price;
            count = count + 1;
        }       
}
    avrg = sum/count;
    System.out.println("Average price of books published after 2000:"+avrg);
```

Everything seems to be running smoothly till the part I want the names of the books (and average price) published. I get this as a result:

```
Please enter details for five books!
Enter Book Title, Author Last Name, Year and Price:
...
Average price of books published after 2000:NaN
```

It doesn't even show the names.I'm quite confused and I have no idea if this is the best way to do what I want to do. I will appreciate some help.

Comment: *"and store my new objects in an array"* that's not happening in your code

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of static variables in the Book class? Hint: you most likely do not need them to be static

Comment: Well, ok, how do I make it happen?
@cricket_007 If, they are not static I'm getting some errors. Completely clueless here. :/

Comment: where you declare sum variable and if you declare it please initialize it with 0

Comment: There is a clear difference between class variables and instance variables. You currently have class variables (all Book instances share one price, author, name, etc). Remove the static and you have instance variables (each Book has its own price, author, name). The sum and the average do not belong to an instance of a Book object.

Comment: @uzaif isn't 0.0F doing the same job?

Comment: I suggest you make a `Book.java` file as well as a `Main.java` file. You seem to be combining the Main class with an object class, which is causing you confusion and errors

Comment: @cricket_007 will try this now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Follow Java naming conventions. The class should be `Book` because it is a singlular object.

`public class Book {`

And your array should be plural.

`Book [] books = new Book[5];`

2) Use instance variables, not class variables, for the properties that belong to an individual book. This requires you to remove `static` from name, author, year, and price.

3) "*I am trying to take the user input and store my new objects in an array.*" Your code that you posted does not store new objects in the array. This explains both why no names are printed and why NaN is in your output, because the array is empty.

Try to store a `new Book()` into the array.

```
    System.out.println("Enter Book Title, Author Last Name, Year and Price:");
    Book b = new Book();
    b.name = in.next();
   ... 
   books[i] = b; // stored
```

4) You need to loop over the Book objects in the array to access their properties. You can use an enhanced for loop since you don't need the index variable anyway.

```
double sum = 0;
for (Book b : books){
    if (b.year >= 2000) {} 
    sum += b.price;
} 
System.out.println(sum);
if (books.length > 0) {
    System.out.println(sum / books.length);
}
```

5) Take that loop and make it a method. For example, `public static double totalPriceOfBooksAfterYear(Book[] books, int year)` and have it `return sum`. You can use that value to calculate the average.

Comment: THANK YOU, all of this explains so much more than this book I am trying to learn from!!!
I've done everything you suggested and it works perfectly, except for the part were I get ALL book outputted (instead of only those after 2000). I guess I'll figure it out after I read more articles.
You were very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

NaN means "Not a Number" and it signals a bad math operation, like zero divided by zero, that is your case: if no book meets the criteria count=0  and sum=0.0F and there you have it.

Comment: That's good to know, but what about my book names? Any ideas?

Comment: An integer division by would trigger an Exception but you do not show the type of variable sum, bug given price is a float I assume we have a float division here

Comment: Well and you need a `0.0F` for the dividend to get `NaN`. Another number would result in `Infinity`. But since you're right with *"if no book meets the criteria"* the `sum` variable is probably also `0.0F`.

Answer (score 0):

NaN means "Not a Number" .
If there aren't any books (Books.year >= 2000) in this condition it causes a division by zero error.Because your count variable is getting 0 .
In 
avrg = sum/count; is not checking weather you have a count more than 0.
Place a if condition to check that,

```
    if(count>=0){ 
      avrg = sum/count;
      System.out.println("Average price of books published after 2000:"+avrg);
}
```

For the book name use getName method insted of Books.name
As an example :

```
Books books = new Books();
System.out.println(books.getName());
```

And check your books for year 2000 or more like this

```
if(book[j].year >= 2000)
```

instead of

```
if(Books.year >= 2000)
```

Because you are using and array type object you need to specify which index you want to look into

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't share this part of your code but do you actually store the inputs in an Book object and then store it in the array? When you create the array it creates 5 Book objects with all null values.

When you're finding the years, none of them qualify since they're all null. This means the count is also staying as a 0. Dividing by 0 is giving the NaN error. The error doesn't show up in the

```
sum = sum + Books.price;
```

line because it's never reaching that state.

Also,

```
if (Books.year >= 2000)
```

is checking if the class has a year >= 2000 and not checking a specific object.

Try something like:

```
if(book[j].year >= 2000)
```

Comment: Nope. That's my whole code. I thought I was storing values in an array with this line:
Books [] book = new Books[5];
but I am obviously wrong.

Comment: "it's never reaching that state" Yes it is. The array has 5 null values. `Books.price` is 0, and `book[j].property` will only work correctly if the variables weren't static

Comment: @Tanya100, The line Books[] book = new Books[5] only initializes the variable as in telling the compiler that the variable book is an array of Books objects of size 5. You need to store the values with something like book[i] = ... but I see you've found that solution form someone else.

Comment: @cricket_007 I meant that it's never reaching that state as in the if statement is always working like if(null >= 2000) which is obviously false so it's not working

Comment: But `Books.year` is an int, not Integer object, so it's just 0, not null